# Boost::Asio Async write failed

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I am porting an application which uses Boost::Asio to an embedded system.

I have already cross-compiled boost 1.57.0 binaries for the board using its BSP.  To test the libraries working, I ran two http server examples that use synchronized and asynchronized writing respectively.

The Sync version runs fine; while the Async one failed at writing.  It returned error "Operation canceled".

Can anyone point out where I should look for?  Thanks.

```
/*
 * Boost::Asio async example
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
using ip::tcp;

struct CHelloWorld_Service
{
        CHelloWorld_Service(io_service &iosev)
                :m_iosev(iosev),m_acceptor(iosev, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1000))
        {}

        void start()
        {
                boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> psocket(new tcp::socket(m_iosev));
                m_acceptor.async_accept(*psocket,
                        boost::bind(&CHelloWorld_Service::accept_handler, this, psocket, _1));
        }

        void accept_handler(boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> psocket, error_code ec)
        {
                if(ec) return;
                start();
                std::cout << psocket->remote_endpoint().address() << std::endl;
                boost::shared_ptr<std::string> pstr(new std::string("hello async world!"));
                psocket->async_write_some(buffer(*pstr),
                        boost::bind(&CHelloWorld_Service::write_handler, this, pstr, _1, _2));
        }

        void write_handler(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> pstr, error_code ec,
                size_t bytes_transferred)
        {
                if(ec)
                std::cout<< "Failed to send! " << boost::system::system_error(ec).what() << std::endl;
                else
                std::cout<< *pstr << " has been sent" << std::endl;
        }

        private:
                io_service &m_iosev;
                ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        io_service iosev;
        CHelloWorld_Service sev(iosev);
        sev.start();
        iosev.run();

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `async_write_some` call you forget to hold a reference to the socket instance.

This causes the `socket` object to be destructed, and as part of the destructor, all pending asynchronous operations are canceled. This explains that you receive `ec` `operation_aborted`.

Fix it either by adding the `socket` pointer to the bound arguments, or alternatively use the `enable_shared_from_this` idiom with your `CSession` type.

### Using *more* `shared_pointer` magic:

Here's the "simplest" edit:

```
void write_handler(
        boost::shared_ptr<std::string> pstr, 
        boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> /*keepalive!*/, 
        error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) 
{
    if(ec)
        std::cout<< "Failed to send! " << boost::system::system_error(ec).what() << "\n";
    else
        std::cout<< *pstr << " has been sent (" << bytes_transferred << " bytes transferred)\n";
}
```

Which should be bound like:

```
    psocket->async_write_some(ba::buffer(*pstr),
            boost::bind(&CService::write_handler, this, pstr, psocket,
                ba::placeholders::error, ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ad1d8b189948045)</kbd>**

Several style improvements

- not `using namespace`
- using the `asio` placeholders (not `_1`, `_2`)

Prints:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp -pthread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem && ./a.out& while sleep .1; do nc 127.0.0.1 6767; done
127.0.0.1
hello async world!hello async world! has been sent (18 bytes transferred)
127.0.0.1
hello async world!hello async world! has been sent (18 bytes transferred)
127.0.0.1
hello async world!hello async world! has been sent (18 bytes transferred)
...
```

### Using `CSession` (enable_shared_from_this)

This is the other idiom, and it avoid spelling out all the shared-pointers.

Instead of keeping spearate shared pointers to the socket and buffer, you make a class to contain both:

```
struct CSession : boost::enable_shared_from_this<CSession> {
    CSession(ba::io_service &iosev)
        :m_iosev(iosev), m_sock(m_iosev)
    {}

    void do_response();

  private:
    void write_handler(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred);

    ba::io_service &m_iosev;
    tcp::socket m_sock;
    std::string response;
};
```

And now the bind looks like:

```
boost::bind(&CSession::write_handler,
     shared_from_this(), /* keep-alive! */
     ba::placeholders::error, ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred)
```

Much simpler. Session management is the responsibility of the `CService`, like before:

```
void start()
{
    auto session = boost::make_shared<CSession>(m_iosev);
    m_acceptor.async_accept(session->m_sock,
            boost::bind(&CService::accept_handler, this, session, ba::placeholders::error));
}

void accept_handler(boost::shared_ptr<CSession> session, error_code ec) {
    if(ec) {
        std::cerr << "Accept failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    } else {
        session->do_response();
        start();
    }
}
```

Again **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f525068cf66611b)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
using ba::ip::tcp;

namespace HelloWorld {

    struct CSession : boost::enable_shared_from_this<CSession> {
        CSession(ba::io_service &iosev)
            :m_iosev(iosev), m_sock(m_iosev)
        {}

        void do_response() {
            response = "hello async world!\n";
            std::cout << m_sock.remote_endpoint().address() << std::endl;

            m_sock.async_write_some(ba::buffer(response),
                    boost::bind(&CSession::write_handler,
                        shared_from_this(), /* keep-alive! */
                        ba::placeholders::error, ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }

      private:

        void write_handler(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) 
        {
            if(ec)
                std::cout<< "Failed to send! " << boost::system::system_error(ec).what() << "\n";
            else
                std::cout<< response << " has been sent (" << bytes_transferred << " bytes transferred)\n";
        }

        ba::io_service &m_iosev;

        friend class CService;
        tcp::socket m_sock;

        std::string response;
    };

    struct CService
    {
        CService(ba::io_service &iosev)
            :m_iosev(iosev),m_acceptor(iosev, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 6767))
        {}

        void start() {
            auto session = boost::make_shared<CSession>(m_iosev);
            m_acceptor.async_accept(session->m_sock,
                    boost::bind(&CService::accept_handler, this, session, ba::placeholders::error));
        }

        void accept_handler(boost::shared_ptr<CSession> session, error_code ec) {
            if(ec) {
                std::cerr << "Accept failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            } else {
                session->do_response();
                start();
            }
        }

      private:
        ba::io_service &m_iosev;
        tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    };
}

int main() {
    ba::io_service iosev;

    using namespace HelloWorld;

    CService sev(iosev);
    sev.start();
    iosev.run();
}
```

With similar output.

Comment: Added a live sample using the session idiom as well: **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f525068cf66611b)** The recorded livestream is available for future review: [around the 1h:01m mark](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/find-newest-file-and-session-idiom-in-asio/). ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: May I ask why it is better to use boost placeholders rather than the standard ones ?

Comment: They're the documented interface. The numeric placeholders may be equivalent (haven't checked) but that would be an implementation detail. Also, in general it is _very good_  to be "literate" (express intent in the code)

Comment: It works!  Thanks for the fix and the detail explanation.