# error error: no type named 'type' while calling ioService()->post(std::bind(some argmumet)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, stdbind

```
class LogSyslogTest{
 using LogSyslogCbFn = std::function<status(Ipc::Instream& stream)>;
static void v4Handler(const LogSyslogHdr& logSyslogHdr, const Ipc::Ipv4& ipv4,
                        const Layer4Bytes& l4Bytes, CbFn fn) {
        Ipc::Outstream out;
        out << logSyslogHdr;
        out << ipv4;
        out << l4Bytes.sPort;
        out << l4Bytes.dPort;
        Ipc::Instream in{out.data(), out.size()};
        fn(in);
}
}
//calling using gtest
Test F(LogSyslogTest, Ipv4Test) {
    LogSyslogHdr logSyslogHdr;
    getLogSyslogHdrIpv4(logSyslogHdr); //fills data

    Ipc::Ipv4 ipv4;
    getIpv4Hdr(ipv4);  //fills data

    Layer4Bytes l4Bytes;
    getL4Bytes1(l4Bytes);  //fills data

    for (int itr = 0; itr < 10000; ++itr) {
        ioService()->post(std::bind(LogSyslogTest::v4Handler, logSyslogHdr,
                                    ipv4, l4Bytes,Handler::processLog));
}
```

This is the abstract code snippet. When compiling this, i am getting following errors.
Error 1-->

```
/volume/evo/files/opt/poky/3.0.2-10/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_context.hpp:190:5: error: static assertion failed: CompletionHandler type requirements not met^M
  190 |     BOOST_ASIO_LEGACY_COMPLETION_HANDLER_CHECK(^M
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^M
```

Error 2-->

```
/volume/evo/files/opt/poky/3.0.2-10/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/include/c++/9.2.0/functional:443:8: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*&(LogSyslogHdr&, Ipc::Ipv4&, Layer4Bytes&, AftStatus (&)(Ipc::Istream<Ipc::ImMutable>&, const PacketService::AmPktIoHdr&)))(const LogSyslogHdr&, const Ipc::Ipv4&, const Layer4Bytes&, std::function<Status(Ipc::Istream<Ipc::ImMutable>&)>)>'^M
  443 |  using _Res_type_impl^M
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~^M
```

Error 2 is repeated 4 times. I tried to pass the arguments using std::ref, still i am facing the same issue.
Can someone help me understand whats going wrong here?

Comment: `std::bind(LogSyslogTest::v4Handler, //...` shouldn't that be `std::bind( &LogSyslogTest::v4Handler, //...`

Comment: tried that..But still hitting the same issue

Comment: related to this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709819/why-must-a-boost-asio-handler-be-copy-constructible. "By defining BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_HANDLER_TYPE_REQUIREMENTS, one can disable the explicit type checking..."

Comment: How is `CbFn` related to the shown `LogSyslogCbFn`, and to `Handler::processLog`? There is not enough info to construct a repro.

Answer (score 1):

For Error 1, looking at [Boost 1.74, io_context.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/boost/asio/impl/io_context.hpp), one finds the following lines:

```
// If you get an error on the following line it means that your handler does
// not meet the documented type requirements for a LegacyCompletionHandler.
BOOST_ASIO_LEGACY_COMPLETION_HANDLER_CHECK(
    LegacyCompletionHandler, handler) type_check;
```

Error 2 refers to the type `std::function<Status(Ipc::Istream<Ipc::ImMutable>&)>` but you have `std::function<status(Ipc::Instream& stream)>`.  Whether or not the stream types are compatible I don't know, but `status` is not `Status`.